# Javascript/Python/d3JS: refresh html page when underlying JSON changes

Tags: javascript, python, json, d3.js

I'm controlling a d3JS interface from another platform.  The workflow: Data->Python to create JSON->d3JS to generate graphic->load the html page locally in a browser.

Is anyone aware of a way within this workflow to force a page reload when the JSON data is updated?

Comment: You would have to instrument your browser from within python.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a problem of how to push updates from the server to the client.

There are two approaches:

1. Fake it. You could use AJAX polling to periodically ask the server whether new data is available.
2. Do it for real. You could use WebSockets to push the data from the server to the client when an update occurs.

With the new data in hand, it should be simple to bind in D3 via the General Update Pattern. See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

If you must reload the page, you can also use either of these approaches to trigger it.